# Slider stop at the end of playing audio

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avaudioplayer, uislider

In my project I am using an AVAudioPlayer to play my saved audio.I am showing the slider for playing audio. The value of the slider is set using the current time property of the player.
playSlider.value = avAudioPlayer.currentTime;
This is the timer code

```
updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(updateCurrentTime) userInfo:p repeats:YES];



//Calls the update current time function 
- (void)updateCurrentTime
{
    [self updateCurrentTimeForPlayer:self.player];
}


//Updates the current time while the audio is playing
-(void)updateCurrentTimeForPlayer:(AVAudioPlayer *)avAudioPlayer
{
    currentTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", (int)avAudioPlayer.currentTime / 60, (int)avAudioPlayer.currentTime % 60, nil];
    playSlider.value = avAudioPlayer.currentTime;

    if (playSlider.value==playSlider.minimumValue) 
    {
        moveToBeginningButton.enabled = NO;
        rewindButton.enabled = NO;
        NSLog(@"PlaySliderMaxValue1 === %f",playSlider.maximumValue);
        NSLog(@"PlaySliderValue1 === %f",playSlider.value);
    }
    else  
    {  
        moveToBeginningButton.enabled = YES;
        rewindButton.enabled = YES; 
        NSLog(@"PlaySliderMaxValue2 === %f",playSlider.maximumValue);
        NSLog(@"PlaySliderValue2 === %f",playSlider.value);

    }
}
```

The maximum value of slider is set as follows

playSlider.maximumValue = audioPlayer.duration;

The problem that I am experiencing is that the slider point will always return to the beginning of the audio after playing.Is this a bug? How can I change this? Please provide your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say whether this is a bug or not, But try using delegate methods of `AVAudioPlayer`. In `didFinishPlaying` method set Slider value to maximumValue. This could be one of the solution.

Comment: I tried that but the slider moves to the beginning after playing audio

Comment: ok Then I think its your NSTimer problem. Just make the timer invalidate as soon as the song is finished playing instead of re-initializing... I think it may be because of that. You can invalidate timer in AVAudioPlayer Delegate methods. Also allocate nil to variable.

Answer (score 1):

Print the value of avAudioPlayer.currentTime before assigning it to playslider.value
I think at the end it will become zero. and it will assign zero to playslider.value

Comment: The thing I noticed here is that the value of avAudioPlayer.currentTime is never getting equal to avAudioPlayer.duration at the end.

Comment: It just jumps before reaching the end.